# Using server-sent events : how to store a connection to a client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-sent-events

I there,

I have setup a SSE connection between a react-native app and a NodeJS server.
I followed some guidelines to set it up in client side, polyfilling `EventSource` and all, this is pretty straight forward.
But on the server side, I have some issue finding out how to store the connection with the client. I chose store the Response in a `global` object, but I have the feeling this is not the proper way to do. Can somebody advise ?

Here is my code below

```js
const SSE_RESPONSE_HEADER = {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'X-Accel-Buffering': 'no'
};

const getUserId = (req, from) => {
  try {
    // console.log(from, req.body, req.params)
    if (!req) return null;
    if (Boolean(req.body) && req.body.userId) return req.body.userId;
    if (Boolean(req.params) && req.params.userId) return req.params.userId;
    return null
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('getUserId error', e)
    return null;
  }
}

global.usersStreams = {}

exports.setupStream = (req, res, next) => {

  let userId = getUserId(req);
  if (!userId) {
    next({ message: 'stream.no-user' })
    return;
  }

  // Stores this connection
  global.usersStreams[userId] = {
    res,
    lastInteraction: null,
  }

  // Writes response header.
  res.writeHead(200, SSE_RESPONSE_HEADER);

  // Note: Heatbeat for avoidance of client's request timeout of first time (30 sec)
  const heartbeat = {type: 'heartbeat'}
  res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(heartbeat)}\n\n`);
  global.usersStreams[userId].lastInteraction = Date.now()

  // Interval loop
  const maxInterval = 55000;
  const interval = 3000;
  let intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (!global.usersStreams[userId]) return;
    if (Date.now() - global.usersStreams[userId].lastInteraction < maxInterval) return;
    res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(heartbeat)}\n\n`);
    global.usersStreams[userId].lastInteraction = Date.now()
  }, interval);


  req.on("close", function() {
    let userId = getUserId(req, 'setupStream on close');
    // Breaks the interval loop on client disconnected
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    // Remove from connections
    delete global.usersStreams[userId];
  });

  req.on("end", function() {
    let userId = getUserId(req, 'setupStream on end');
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    delete global.usersStreams[userId];
  });

};

exports.sendStream = async (userId, data) => {
  if (!userId) return;
  if (!global.usersStreams[userId]) return;
  if (!data) return;

  const { res } = global.usersStreams[userId];

  res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify({ type: 'event', data })}\n\n`);
  global.usersStreams[userId].lastInteraction = Date.now();

};
```

Comment: But if we will store res variables in an object, then Don't you think when request grows then there can max memory error allocated to this variable, which we should also have to handle.

Comment: are you there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first tip is to simply get rid of `global`; it's ok to have a variable in your module's closure. Your module can encapsulate this "global" state without making it globally accessible to all other modules.

```
const usersStreams = {};
```

Second, it's probably not impossible for the same user to have multiple connections established. I'd recommend that if you're keying these connections on `userId`, you ought to have the values in `userStreams` for these keys as collections so you can write to multiple. Either that or you'd need a more unique key.

Comment: thanks @Jacob for the answer. Does it mean that it is good practice to store these connections in a variable and not in DB ?

Comment: A DB wouldn't be able to store a connection, since it's not likely possible to be serialized and re-inflated to a working object. Keeping in memory like you've got it works fine, and you have good cleanup code already in place.

Comment: @Jacob But if we will store res variables in an object, then Don't you think when request grows then there can max memory error allocated to this variable, which we should also have to handle.

Comment: @Jacob are you there?

Comment: Not sure how to answer you... of course you run the risk of maxing out on memory, but that doesn't change the fact that a database is not going to be able to store references to things like streams. If you're getting memory issues, you need to either store less state in memory or scale out.